# I want to link my XML file to my HTML page

Tags: html, xml

I have created a XML file I would like for it to be displayed in my HTML page that I also created. Can someone tell me how to do this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Family>
<Mom>Alison</Mom>
<age>44</age>
<son>Ian</son>
<age>8</age>
<son>Seth</son>
</Family>
```

I would like to read that from my html page

Comment: I do not understand. Please show some more details

Answer (score 5):

**a) Simply linking your Xml file**

You can link to your Xml file from a Html page by using Server Side Includes.

If your Webserver is configured to allow this feature (this is usually disabled for security reasons) all you need to do is to rename your Html page to .shtml and add the server side `include` command.

**foo.shtml**

```
<html>
    <head/>
    <body>
    <!--#include file="bar.xml" -->
    </body>
</html>
```

**bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Family>
    <Mom>Alison</Mom>
    <age>44</age>
    <son>Ian</son>
    <age>8</age>
    <son>Seth</son>
</Family>
```

This will show the text `Alison 44 Ian 8 Seth` in your browser.

---

**b) Rendering your Xml file as Html**

If you want to render your complete Xml file as a Html page **wenuxas** has the correct answer for you.

---

**c) Embedding your Xml file into your Html page**

If your Xml document represents only a fragment of your final page [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) - language for transforming XML documents. Maybe this would fit your needs.

I have modified your provided XML a little bit, because I think it is not structured well. So if we have such document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="bla.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
<family>
   <person>
      <role>Mom</role>
      <name>Alison</name>
      <age>44</age>
   </person>
   <person>
      <role>Father</role>
      <name>Ben</name>
      <age>45</age>
   </person>
   <person>
      <role>Son</role>
      <name>Ian</name>
      <age>8</age>
   </person>
</family>
```

The XSLT file would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Family</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <th>Role</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="family/person">
          <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="role"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="age"/></td>
          </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1 to give you an incentive to replace `for-each` with a template ;-)

Comment: The files should be the same name just different extensions is my understanding

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to display the XML contents as they look in the file, you can search and replace all brackets (< becomes &lt; and > becomes &gt;), then paste the result in between <pre> and </pre> tags.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the most common way is to use a server-side development platform such as ASP.NET to read the XML file and then format it into the page markup.

If there's a more direct way to include XML content in an HTML page, I'm not familiar with it.