# Link Xml file to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xml

i have created a simple xml file and an html file to display the xml file details but its not working..its in the same folder an all...

here is my xml file :

student.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Student>
<Name>Student</Name>
<Gender>Boy</Gender>
<City>Mumbai</City>
<PhoneNumbers>42607700, 42607701</PhoneNumbers>
<Email>student@aurus.com</Email>
</Student>
```

Html file :

studentDetails.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="loadxmldoc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("student.xml");

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Student");

for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write(x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("<br>");
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and Javascript file :

loadXMLDoc.js

```
    function loadXMLDoc(student)
{

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else // code for IE5 and IE6
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

 xhttp.open("GET",student,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
}
```

plz help

Comment: [**It**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682904/i-want-to-link-my-xml-file-to-my-html-page) might help you.

Comment: hi Hanzallah..i tried this <!--#include file="student.xml" --> but it dint work..

Comment: Above in your script src you have written the file name in lower case while below you have written that in camel casing. as loadXMLDoc.js. Ckeck that too. Or Go to the developer console in the browser to point out the problem

Comment: checked out the name thing..still doesnt work...in dev mode it shows : Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest'...:( thx neways

Comment: Browser? check it in Firefox or IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an example for you that is working well in Firefox but not in Chrome. I think that is because you are requesting the xml file locally. That should be through a server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","students.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table><tr><th>Students</th><th>Age</th></tr>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("student");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<tr><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("age")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

students.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<STUDENTS>
    <student>
        <name>Hanzallah</name>
        <age>20</age>
        <exp>Everything</exp>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Afgan</name>
        <age>22</age>
        <exp>Nothing</exp>
    </student>
</STUDENTS>
```

Comment: ya man it works in safari, not in chrome. So it was the browsers problem after all. Thanks man(Y)